# Mac doesn't download software updates automatically

Tags: macos, software-update, ventura

I have "download new updates when available" checked in System Settings -> General -> Software Updates -> Automatic Updates.

[image]

Yet when I click on the Ventura 13.1 update, it starts downloading. This update has been available for almost a week, why hasn't my Mac downloaded it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but an educated guess:
It only checks weekly. In the first few days of a new release notifications of it are staggered so the servers don't get hit with a million download requests an hour. You just happen to have hit that gap.

If you'd waited another week, it would have done it in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading automatic updates has two caveats:

1. It will never be as fast to detect updates as manual updates. Apple designs the automatic update system to roll out slowly to avoid releasing a bad update to the entire install base before they notice the problem. For a major update, expect months to go by before it's guaranteed the system will have tried to install it. For minor updates, the time varies.

   Evidence of this is clear: security updates have been rolled out to every back over the course of mere hours in the past and continue to be rolled out quickly when needed. There is no evidence that the timing of update installation is unintentional.
2. The other problem, possibly here, is that the system is very conservative at determining when it's allowed to install an update. Laptops should be plugged in, and you can't have applications open that don't support the system restoration features needed to close and reopen them seamlessly. Other things may interfere as well.

Comment: My question is about downloading, not installing, so #2 is not really my concern. I still want to control when the update is installed, I don't want it rebooting without me telling it.

Comment: Yeah, then in your case I suspect #1 is the situation. 1 week is not longer enough for the auto-update to be guaranteed to kick in, by design.

Comment: I wonder why they need to spread this out over weeks. Microsoft has "patch Tuesday" every month, and everyone gets it the same day (although at different times). But maybe they justify it because they don't send out routine updates so often.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, "Download new updates when available" simply doesn't work.  I've waited months for it to download and no matter how long it's been, it always starts the download when I click "Update".

Comment: Thanks for confirming you’re affected as well.  Odd, we have very good results from this setting at work and I also at home rely on it and it’s solid. I wonder why some people are having problems. Perhaps the networks they are on show poor `networkQuality`

Comment: At work, sometimes they use the Apple-supplied tools for managing corporate environments, which has specific tools for downloading so each person in the organization doesn't have to do it.

Comment: This is available to everyone now. In the past you need to run Apple Server and then the Server app to get a caching server. Now any macOS can act as this as the functionality is built into all the OS. In your case, run `AssetCacheLocatorUtil` and look for any lines where there is a non-zero number of caches found. **Found 1 content cache** is the situation now on my network at home... There's really good documentation on managing this if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you.  That's helpful.